# Why is the water pumped out of the holding tank a minute before Falcon 9 liftoff?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, water, acoustic-sound-suppression

SpaceX Falcon 9 - starlink mission on October 5. Video :

Why is the water discharged at T- 01m:30s from the holding tank far away from the launch pad?
This was also observed in the scrub which happened a week ago.

Water flow appears to be too far away to be considered Sound Suppression System which pumps water near engine nozzle seconds before liftoff .

Happy end to Scrubtober!!

Comment: If the water should not only suppress the sound but also protect the launch pad from the heat of the rocket engine exhaust, some time and water is needed to wet all structures.

Comment: @uwe I think he means, look at the water tower on the right, and it seems to be venting water from up high...  Not the Niagara system itself.

Comment: IIRC, they top it off by letting it overflow & then just turning off the valve